# Where are the project properties in visual studio 2017 when in Folder View?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Ultimately I try to set a file to be copied to the build output directory.
But I ran in to the problem of not being able to locate the project properties. I know it should be there, am I overlooking something?

I follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cpp/ide/general-property-page-project
In the first line it suggests:

> When you right-click on a project node in in Solution Explorer, and select Properties,

Assuming that I know what is referred to by the project node. Well I right-clicked and left-clicked about everything and anything in the whole VS and nowhere I find any properties. Also not of the file that should be included in the build. It feels like one of those cases of a blindspot or something, maybe someone out there can help me out?

[image]

Comment: Found that. It is empty

Comment: according to your screenshot, you right clicked on folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am afraid you are in `Folder View` of the Solution Explorer window which will not show your `*.proj` files, in order to change to project view click on the right icon next to `Home` and everything will be back to normal.(or at least as expected)

Answer (score 3):

Click on **View > Properties Window**

[image: VS17 Porperties window]

To change the Solution Explorer View mode, click the button highlighted below:

[image: Solution Explorer View mode]

In your case it would be:

[image]

Comment: did that, but it is empty

Comment: You need to click on the file and not the folder to see the property details.

Comment: Ok I went back to fileview in solution explorer, clicked on a file and then properties window, and it is still empty

Comment: From your screenshot it appears you are in Folder View mode on the Solution Explorer. You need to changes this to the Solution Mode. I've updated the Answer to show you how todo this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the projects in Solution Explorer, they have different icons to the other files.

Project files tend to have a square border:

- Project file [image]
- Source file [image]

I accept it is difficult to tell the difference - there as so many different icons.

Comment: i don't think it answered my question but interesting none the less